# Image median threshold in java

Tags: java, image-processing, threshold

i am doing the median threshold. The concept is i will insert an color image, then i will use the array.sort to get the median value of each rgb value. then write the new image based on the median value.
Here is the code.

```
public class medianthreshold{
    public static void main(String[] a)throws Throwable{
        File f=new File("C:\\Users\\asd\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication34\\images.jpg");                               //Input Photo File
        Color[] pixel=new Color[9];
        int[] R=new int[9];
        int[] B=new int[9];
        int[] G=new int[9];

        File output=new File("C:\\Users\\asd\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication34\\outputmedian.jpg");


                img.setRGB(i,j,new Color(R[4],B[4],G[4]).getRGB());
            }
        ImageIO.write(img,"jpg",output);
    }
}
```

And i would like to enhance it,make it become black and white image,by putting a condition, if the pixel value of each rgb is less than median, then the value should be 0 (represent white color), else the value become 0xFFFFFF (represent black color). 225x225 is the image width and height.

The problem im facing now is i duno which part i should put to make sure every pixel value will change to 0 or 0xFFFFF in each R[4],G[4],B[4] which represent the median value of rgb. The output image should have 0 and 1 of pixel value which also is a white and black image.

Comment: It totally depends upon your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

1. You said median, but you computed the mean. It's ok, it's just an other ways to do an adaptive global thresholding.
2. In order to make it faster, you should simply use the histogram of the image. It will be faster and simpler to compute the mean or the median value. You can also use the DataBuffer instead of getRGB. Moreover, I strongly advise to use TYPE_3BYTE_BGR images instead of TYPE_INT_RGB.
3. For the mean, you have code source example in ImageJ.
4. 0/1, 0/0xFF or 0/0xFFFF just depends on the image encoding, so respectively TYPE_BINARY, TYPE_BYTE_GRAY or TYPE_USHORT_GRAY when you work with the BufferedImage.

Comment: sorry i am using the mean concept to change to median..and just concept. havent write the code >.<

Comment: Yes, and as I said in 1, it's just an other value.